# How to filter columns that has only null values in redshift sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm working with AWS Redshift and while querying one of my tables I'm getting columns that have only values of null.

```
C1    C2     C3     C4    C5 
--------------------------------
34    43.5   null   75.4   null
null  43.5   null   75.4   null
```

What I would like to get is

```
C1    C2     C4
------------------
34    43.5   75.4
null  43.5   75.4
```

Any ideas on how to get it using SQL or I'll need to get everything and filter it out in the code?

Comment: You'll probably need to filter them out in the code, if you want to. But.... null is also a piece of relevant information, isn't it?

Comment: You can check out this answer but since it's not straight-forward, you might consider filtering with code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038435/sql-conditional-select